# Javascript Getting Key and Values from Object

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new javascript and am having trouble extracting data from an ajax request before loading to a webpage.

The data from the ajax request is something like:

```
{
"success": {
    "user1": [
        ["2018-01-30", {
            "Type": "None",
            "Body": "Message 2"
        }],
        ["2018-01-29", {
            "Type": "None",
            "Body": "Message 1"
        }]
    ],
    "user2": [
        ["2018-01-28", {
            "Type": "None",
            "Body": "Message 2"
        }],
        ["2018-01-27", {
            "Type": "None",
            "Body": "Message 1"
        }]
    ],
    "user3": [
        ["2018-01-26", {
            "Type": "None",
            "Body": "Message 2"
        }],
        ["2018-01-25", {
            "Type": "None",
            "Body": "Message 1"
        }]
    ]
}
```

I can extract the `Type` and `Body` data using the below code, Which lists all the items out on the webpage.

```
$.ajax(
        {
            url : '/ajax_get_messages',
            type: "GET",
            dataType : 'json'
        }).done(function(messages)
        {
            $.each(messages.success, function(index, message)
            {
                $('#messages').append(`
                    <div class='message'>New Sender`)

                $.each(message, function(index, item)
                {
                    $('#messages').append(`
                        <p>Date: ${item[0]} | Type: ${item[1]['Type']} | Body: ${item[1]['Body']}</p>
                    </div>`)
                });
            });
        })
```

What I'm struggling to do is get the user's names `user1`, `user2` etc and put it in place of `New Sender', so all the messages from a user are grouped together in it's own div. I've looked at Object.keys but that didn't seem to be correct for this.

I'm also aware that the appending to the html isn't working correctly because of the `$.each(message, function(index, item)` in the middle. Is there a way around this?

Comment: This looks similar to [Get key and value of object in JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10718473).

Comment: The json you have pasted is throwing syntax error. You should replace it with the correct json response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you provided is invalid, but I cleaned it up. You should be able to use the `index` in the first loop to get the name:

<kbd>[Here's an example](https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/Kooejw?editors=1011)</kbd>

You can always `console.log` the current element in any loop to see exactly what's available to you

[image]

Comment: many thanks. The index worked for the username. Is there a way to make the <p> tag go inside the <div>? At the moment the <div> closes with the <p> tags outside.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that part in the question - yes there is. If I were you, I would build the `.message` as an HTML object and then add it when it's done: https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/Kooejw?editors=1011